# Scraping a RSS url in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rss, rselenium

I am trying to scrape some tags in a list of RSS urls. I have tried using a normal scraping structure with RSelenium (since I have a list of URLs) where I find the html_nodes for the things I am interested in: username, review, title, rating... But I keep getting this error **"user_name: object not found"**. So I was wondering whether or not I should structure the scraping differently because it's a RSS url? I have tried looking at the R-related questions for this and that's where I came up with the structure, but it seemed to work in the related question... Here is my code:

```
selenium_f= rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"))

#start a driver
driver = selenium_f$client

scrapped = list()

i <- 1
while(i <= 11){

  url <- corpus_df$reviews_rss_url[i]

  print( paste("Accessing to:", url) )

  driver$navigate(url)

  page_source <- driver$getPageSource()

  URL <- read_html(page_source[[1]])

  results <- URL %>% html_nodes("item")

  records <- vector("list", length = length(results))

  for (ii in (records)) {

    title <- xml_contents(results[ii] %>%  html_nodes("title"))[1] %>%
      html_text(trim = TRUE)

    user_name <- xml_contents(results[ii] %>% html_nodes("user_name"))[1] %>% 
      html_text(trim = TRUE)


    rating <- xml_contents(results[ii] %>% html_nodes("rss > channel > item:nth-child(11) > user_rating"))[1] %>% 
      html_text(trim = TRUE)

    review <- xml_contents(results[ii] %>% html_nodes("rss > channel > item:nth-child(11) > user_review"))[1] %>% 
      html_text(trim = TRUE)
}



  #remDr$close()

  scrapped[[i]] =  data.frame(name = user_corpus[i,'name'],
                             url = corpus_df[i,'review_rss_url'],
                             title = ifelse(length(title) > 0, title, NA),
                             username = ifelse(length(user_name) > 0, user_name, NA),
                             rating = ifelse(length(rating) > 0, rating, NA),
                             review = ifelse(length(review) > 0, review, NA))

  i = i + 1

}
```

Comment: I don't know which kind of web sites are you scraping, but when you use Selenium to scrape something, in your project, you have to consider the break with `Sys.sleep(seconds) `. You have to give the time to the javascript or similar to runs and to upload the results that you need.

Comment: Hi, I think I figured it out; the RSS is XML hence I can't directly access the html tags. I am going to close this question now. Thanks for trying to help me though :)